# Blender keeps crashing when I open a file

Tags: blend-files

Never had a problem.... until now, it opens fine, but it instantly crashes when I open a file, any file. It works while I work in the New/Start Up file, but it also crashes when I save that and try to Open it...

It started crashing after I (a few minutes ago) deleted all files from the C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp folder... where it stores some of the .blend files... (I guess for a backup)... not sure if it stores any system/app files there also....

Any idea how may I solve this and or check what is causing the problem....

Thanks guys

Comment: I did reinstall Blender, btw.... into the same folder... will try to install somewhere else.... Oh and when I hit Recover Last session it says it can not find quit.blend file from that Temp folder....

Answer (score 1):

Hell yeah. Removed Blender and installed it into a new folder. Works fine. Phewwwww.